# Nginx Block access to certain file types (like .txt)

Tags: nginx, http

my goal:
Block any request that requests these file types:

```
{random name{.txt
.md
.git
```

If the user tries to access any of the "blocked" file types, i want to return a HTTP 404. This should happen on *all* folders, not just the root folder

my Server code so far

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        root /forum;
        index index.php;
        server_name forum.example.net;
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        }
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
        location ~ \.md {
        deny all;
        return 404;
        }
        location ~ /\.txt {
        deny all;
        return 404;
        }
        location ~ /\.git {
        deny all;
        return 404;
        }
}
```

When i try going to the url: /folder/test.md

It downloads, and not sending a Deny all, which i want to block it

how can i do this?

Comment: try to put those block before   
location / {  
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;  
        }

also remove / before \.filetype, because it will only match url like something/subdir/.txt

Comment: Why is there a `deny all` in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Block the filetypes:

```
.md
.git
{anything}.txt
```

add to server block:

```
location ~\.(git|txt|md)$ {
 deny all;
 return 404;
}
```

if user accesses /folder/1.txt, 1.txt will return has HTTP 404